# SQL include and exclude

Tags: sql, join, include

I am trying to return customers that have had any of the following words appear on their account: 'Communication','Response','Registration', 'Investigation'
And usually when any of the words above are on the account the word 'GS' should be added by the advisor onto the database. I'm trying to build a script to find the accounts where 'GS' has not been added as per below script. The script runs without error but still returns accounts with 'GS' and any of the words 'Communication','Response','Registration', 'Investigation'

```
Select* 
FROM ENQUIRY.enquiried a
Left Outer Join ENQUIRE.REQUEST_TYPE b 
ON a.request_type = b.ID
Where b.description NOT LIKE 'GS'
AND b.description in ('Communication','Response','Registration', 
'Investigation')
```

Comment: I think to the first part of the `WHERE` clause, shouldn't the `LIKE` be: `NOT LIKE '%GS%'`, or possibly `NOT LIKE '% GS%'` to avoid other potential words such as `TAGS`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM ENQUIRY.enquiried a
LEFT OUTER JOIN ENQUIRE.REQUEST_TYPE b 
    ON a.request_type = b.ID
WHERE b.description IN ('Communication','Response','Registration', 
'Investigation')
```

Comment: the user is using a front end system where they can only select predefined words like 'GS' and or 'Communication','Response','Registration', 
'Investigation'

Comment: So what i need is when any of the 4 records/words above are present for a customer only return records that do not have the record 'GS' also on the customer account.

Answer (score 0):

Can you share some sample data and schema?
I believe the not like condition shouldn't even be necessary as we are explicitly mentioning values with the 'IN' operator.

```
SELECT *
FROM   enquiry.enquiried a
       LEFT OUTER JOIN enquire.request_type b
                    ON a.request_type = b.id
WHERE  b.description IN ( 'Communication', 'Response', 'Registration',
                          'Investigation');
```